# $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Tags: inequality

If n be a positive integer, prove that

$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

**My try 1 :**

To prove $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}$

Consider two positive integers $(m+1)$ & $(m-2)$ where $m$$\gt$2 and then apply AM$\gt$GM

$\frac{(m+1)+(m-2)}{2}$$\gt$$\sqrt{(m+1)(m-2)}$

$\frac{2m-1}{2(m+1)}$$\gt$$\sqrt{\frac{m-2}{m+1}}$

This implies  $\frac{5\cdot7\cdots(2n-1)}{8\cdot10\cdots2(n+1)}$$\gt$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdots\frac{n-2}{n+1}}$
**(FAILED TRY)**

**My Try 2:**

Consider two positive integers $(m+1)$ & $m$ and then apply AM$\gt$GM

$\frac{(m+1)+m}{2}$$\gt$$\sqrt{(m+1)m}$

$\frac{2m+1}{2(m+1)}$$\gt$$\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}$

now $\prod_{m=1}^{(n-1)}$$\frac{2m+1}{2(m+1)}$$\gt$$\prod_{m=1}^{(n-1)}\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}$  implies

$\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n-1)}{4\cdot6\cdot8\cdots2n}$$\gt$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{n}{n+1}}$

$\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdots2n}$$\gt$$\frac{1}{2}$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}}$
**(Proved the first part)**

Please give me some hint to prove the second part of the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about? Good job on MathJax though.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: In the second try on the second inequality right hand side denominator should be $(m+1)^2$ inside the square root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2n-1}\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3}}\\
\sqrt{4n^2-1}=\color{fuchsia}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n-1)}<\sqrt{4n^2}}=2n\\
\color{fuchsia}{\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}}}\\
\prod^{n}_{i=1}\frac{2i-1}{2i}<\prod^{n}_{j=1}\sqrt{\frac{2j-1}{2j+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}
$$

---

And I have another sophisticated solution:

Use this integration as a preparation:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
I_m&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^m x \text{d}x \quad(m=0,1,2,...)\\
&=& 
\begin{cases} \frac{(m-1)!!}{m!!}\frac{\pi}{2},~\text{m is even} \\
\frac{(m-1)!!}{m!!}, ~~~~\text{m is odd} \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Consider inequality $\quad \sin^{2n+1}x<\sin^{2n}x<\sin^{2n-1}x \quad(n\rightarrow \infty ;x\in(0,\pi/2))$, and there goes integral inequality:
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\sin^{2n+1}x\text{d}x<\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\sin^{2n}x\text{d}x<\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\sin^{2n-1}x\text{d}x $$

$$1<\frac{(2n+1)!!(2n-1)!!}{[(2n)!!]^2}\frac{\pi}{2}<\frac{(2n+1)!!(2n-2)!!}{(2n)!!(2n-1)!!}=\frac{2n+1}{2n}=1$$
Use the Squeeze theorem
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!!(2n-1)!!}{[(2n)!!]^2}\frac{\pi}{2}=1$$
which is:
$${\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\sqrt{\frac{2}{2n+1}}}= \sqrt{\pi}$$
which is:
$${\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}}= \sqrt{\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}} =  \sqrt{\frac{4}{(4n+2)\pi}} $$
And the question is EASILY solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $ A = \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}$ and $B = \frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n+1)} $.

Show that

- $ A < B $
- $ AB = \frac{1}{ 2n+1}$.
- $ A < \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2n+1} }$.